# Dataweave conversion from ArrayList to Object

Tags: dataweave, mule-esb

Hi I am getting a payload as

```
[{"A":"234"},{"A": "123"}]
```

and I simply want the output as

```
{"A":"234", "A": "123"}
```

what script in dataweave can do that?

Comment: Try this script `payload reduce ($$ ++ $)`

Comment: It works for the JSON putput but dont for the java one. I was actually requiring a java one, which I forgot to mention in the question. Although I guess that this might not be possible in Java as "A" is a key and it is always unique !

Comment: You are absolutely right - it is not possible for Java. In Java it is a map. Map does not have duplicated keys. Latest key will overwrite previous one. Your result will be {"A":"123"}